# Тест TCP сервера

Tags: c#, tcp, benchmark

Как проверить сколько TCP соединений может нормально держать сервер? Как проверить производительность TCP сервера?

Comment: Что значит нормально и что значит держать? В каком конкретно состоянии TCP должны находиться у вас соединения чтобы вы считали что сервер их держит нормально?

Comment: Максимальное кол-во открытых TCP соединений зависит от операционной системы, а не от программы.

Comment: Apache Benchmark (ab)

Comment: @ГеннадийП не совсем верно, все же асинхронные сервера могут держать куда больше соединений чем многопоточные при одних и тех же конфигурациях ОС и железа